# How to declare inline functions explicitly?

Tags: c++, inline, declaration

We don't need to declare inline functions explicitly since their implementations are defined in a header file. But for organization purpose, I want to do it. For example

```
// Group declaration firstly for readability.
inline void fooA();
inline void fooB();
inline void fooC();
...

// Implementations
inline void fooA()
{
   ...
}

inline void fooB()
{
   ...
}

inline void fooC()
{
   ...
}
```

My question is: may I need both `inline` keywords in declaration and implementation or one of them can be deleted?

I found an answer there [Forward declaration of inline functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317473/forward-declaration-of-inline-functions) . So this is a repeated question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yep, I thought it looked familiar.  However, my question is for the C language.

Comment: Does the answer there stand here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include it in either the declaration, the definition, or both.

But note that the *definition* must be visible in every compilation unit that uses the function.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need both. You can delete inline keyword in implementation and keep inline keyword when you declare functions... It is same as virtual keyword